# raspberry pi using a webcam to output to a website to view

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am currently working on a project in which I am using a webcam attached to a raspberry pi to then show what the camera is seeing through a website using a client and web server based method through python, However, I need to know how to link the raspberry pi to a website to then output what it sees through the camera while then also outputting it through the python script, but then i don't know where to start
If anyone could help me I would really appreciate it.
Many thanks.

Comment: You should read real time streaming protocols via python.

Comment: You can not do such stuff using python. You need to use ffmpeg and rtmp server like nginx. Then nginx server will convert the stream to HLS parts, and you can play the video on the browser using some js HLS player. Google stuff like "nginx rtmp hls" and "ffmpeg stream camera to rtmp"

Comment: okay but should i code the raspberry pi in that language or a simple one like python?

Answer (score 0):

So one way to do this with python would be to capture the camera image using opencv in a loop and display it to a website hosted on the Pi using a python frontend like flask (or some other frontend). However as others have pointed out, the latency on this would be so bad any processing you wish to do would be nearly impossible.

If you wish to do this without python, take a look at mjpg-streamer, that can pull a video feed from an attached camera and display it on a localhost website. The quality is fairly good on localhost. You can then forward this to the web (if needed) using port forwarding or an application like nginx.

If you want to split the recorded stream into 2 (to forward one to python and to broadcast another to a website), ffmpeg is your best bet, but the FPS and quality would likely be terrible.